# Fullcalendar.io agendaweek is not displaying 'all-day' column when is setted as true

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar.io implementation, and I'm trying to display the `all-day` column, in the `agendaWeek` view with:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: true,
    allDayDefault: true,
    weekNumbers: true,
    editable: false,
    slotDuration: '00:30:00',
    snapDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotEventOverlap: true,
    axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
    lang: 'es',
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2014-06-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2014-06-07',
        end: '2014-06-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2014-06-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2014-06-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2014-06-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2014-06-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2014-06-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2014-06-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2014-06-28'
      }
    ]
  });
```

The problem is: the events are displayed in a list, without format, what I'm doing wrong???

Comment: try removing `allDaySlot: true,`

Comment: Add `allDay: true` to all-day events